# How to remove key from Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have Array objects like below , How to convert this format into Array of objects and remove key.

```
{
  "9417702107": {
    "name": "Sunny",
    "phone": "9417702107",
    "exists": true
  },
  "8826565107": {
    "name": "Gurwinder",
    "phone": "8826565107",
    "exists": true
  }
}
```

How to convert this into below format using javascript:

```
[{
  "name": "Sunny",
  "phone": "9417702107",
  "exists": true
}, {
  "name": "Gurwinder",
  "phone": "8826565107",
  "exists": true
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simple loop:

```
array = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    array.push(obj[key]);
}
```

As in the other answer, there's no guarantee that the elements of the array will be in the same order as in the object.

Answer (score 1):

simply try this

```
var output = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
  return obj[key];
})
```

Note that there is no guarantee that order of items in `output` array will be same as in the order key-values in your object as you see it.

if the order is important, then put an new attribute called `order` in the object itself

```
var obj {
"9417702107": 
 {
  "name": "Sunny",
  "phone": "9417702107",
  "exists": true,
  "order_sequence" : 1
},
"8826565107": {
  "name": "Gurwinder",
  "phone": "8826565107",
  "exists": true,
  "order_sequence" : 1
}
}
```

and then after converting to array, you can sort on the `order_sequence`

```
var output = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
  return obj[key];
}).sort( function(a,b){
   return a.order_sequence - b.order_sequence;
});
```

Comment: but be aware that there's no guarantee in which order the elements will appear in the resulting array

Comment: @Alnitak yes, that is true if this array is generated dynamically.

Comment: @gurvinder372 then what's alternative. vire.??

Comment: @SunnyDhiman with the object, order of key is immaterial and has no meaning since object is supposed to be key-value affair and not item based affair. If the order is important, then the object needs to have an `order` attribute.

Comment: @gurvinder372 ok i got it. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys and for-cycle.

```
var keys = Object.keys(input), output = [];
for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; ++i)
    ouptput.push(input[keys[i]]);
console.log(output);
```

Some tips:
- Cycles in this case gives move performance than map function, because in today JS engines: fewer functions calls, greater performance.
- For-each (for (var k in input) {}) is slower than Object.keys and cycle for/while.

This is acceptable for today implementation Google V8 and Mozilla SpiderMonkey.

Comment: there is any guarantee in order remain same..??